# How to execute javascript inside a URL used in a .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

If file1 uses `.load(file2)` and If file2 has Javascript/Jquery initialization code.  Is there a way to initialize the code inside file2 by file2 when loaded into a container in file1 by file1?

$(document).ready(... doesn't quite work for this.  Remember the code should be inside file2 (the file being loaded should initialize it's own js, is this possible?)

I hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags in the loaded code will be run **if**:

- The tags have no "type" attribute, or of the value of the "type" is "text/javascript" (exactly)
- The ".load()" call is a pure URL, and not a URL + a selector, like "$('.foo').load(url + ' .stuff')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  myImage = new Image()
  myImage.src = "/path/to/file2.js" 
})
```

I hope this code will helps you.

Comment: that won't work inside the file being loaded.. I can call load(url,init) like this, but i cannot just call load(url) and have the url init its own code.